# Bluetooth audio SCO link to multiple devices, only 1 active at a time

Tags: bluetooth

Say my platform or 'Bluetooth Controller' has support for only 1 SCO link over PCM. In this case can I still pair with multiple devices and communicate (Audio) with them alternately? Or my 'Bluetooth Controller' needs to have capability for multiple SCO links per PCM?

Comment: you can use`fork()` to creat a new process and work with it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can still pair more than one devices, but only one attempt to connect SCO socket will succeed. Since you say 'communicate with them alternately' I think that can be accomplished by always call close() to current SCO socket, before connect() for the next one(to a different headset addr).